# Android appcompat showAsAction="never". Submenu doesn't appear

Tags: android, android-appcompat

I have an almost empty android project which uses appcomat.
I have one menu item which needs to be always hidden (shown only in dropdown when it's clicked)

```
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        app:showAsAction="never"/>
```

It's working as expected on my Nexus7 but on Galaxy S3, with Android 4.3, the icon in the actionbar isn't shown at all.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because Galaxy s3 is not tablet and it has `hardware menu` button which will open your menu. So if there is hardware menu button you will not get overflow button.

Comment: Ohh thank you. But is it possible to force display this button on actionbar?

Comment: See [link here](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/compatibility.html). You should not even try to do this. Android system is about consistency. So person using smartphone, for example S3 knows how to use menu button and if in every system app there is no such overflow button your app also should not try to force it.

Comment: If you really need use [link here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20444596/how-to-force-action-bar-overflow-icon-to-show)