# Android differences in menu

Tags: android, menu, actionbarsherlock

I have the following problem:

I compile my application for Android 4.4.2 using actionbarsherlock. When run it on the android 4.4.2 emulator it looks like this:

[image: Android 4.4.2]

When I run this application on my phone with Android 4.0.4 I saw this:

[image: Android 4.0.4]

The menu at the top was gone. How can I fix this?

Сompile this http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/adding-action-items-and-overflow-menu-items-to-action-bar-in-android/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your device or emulator has a physical menu button, the overflow items from action bar are behind it. The menu button is added to actionbar if there is no physical menu button.

Question [How to force action bar overflow icon to show](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20444596/how-to-force-action-bar-overflow-icon-to-show) has an answer on how to put the overflow items to actionbar menu instead of physical menu button.

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever heard of support v7 appcompat ?
Use it's ActionBar.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your phone has hardware menu button.