# Kindle Overflow menu button not appearing

Tags: android, menu, kindle-fire

I'm working on an app for android which has a menu. It works perfectly fine on my ancient phone which has a physical menu button(running 2.2), but on a Kindle Fire the overflow menu button doesn't appear. I'm sorry if this seems like a repeat question but I've tried a lot of the methods listed in other people's answers and haven't had any change.

My menu xml looks like this:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">


<item
    android:id="@+id/action_main"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="@string/action_MainMenu"
    app:showAsAction="never"/>
```

[and so on]

```
            @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

                    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

                    //[here I have a few if statements to rename items or remove unnecessary ones]
                    return true;
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Overflow menu at times doesnt appear for devices with physical Menu key. A very nice hack has been provided by Commonsware for this.

```
 try {
    ViewConfiguration config = ViewConfiguration.get(this);
    Field menuKeyField = ViewConfiguration.class.getDeclaredField("sHasPermanentMenuKey");

   if (menuKeyField != null) {
     menuKeyField.setAccessible(true);
     menuKeyField.setBoolean(config, false);
  }
}
catch (Exception e) {
 // presumably, not relevant
}
```

[Source.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20444596/how-to-force-action-bar-overflow-icon-to-show)

Comment: Thank you for the response. I have tried this and it made no difference. Also this device has no physical menu key.