# ActionBarSherlock menu ForceOverflow not showing

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock, overflow

My problem is that when you open the app is not shown the overflow menu in the actionbar.
If you see en the MainActivity class I have a onOptionsItemSelected for the navigationdrawer, so when I create on the bottom a onCreatedOptionMenu with their respective onOptionsItemSelected fails.
and I dont know how to fix it.

This is what I want

[Image](http://i2.wp.com/blog.stylingandroid.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/basic_app_menu.png)

But nothing appears in the actionbar when I open application

This is my **menu.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
style="@style/Theme.Sherlock">
<item 
    android:id="@+id/more"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_overflow"
    android:title="@string/more"
    android:showAsAction="always"/>

    <menu >
        <item
            android:id="@+id/contacto"
            android:title="@string/contacto"
            android:showAsAction="always|withText"/>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/recomenda"
            android:title="@string/recomenda"
            android:showAsAction="always|withText"/>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/salir"
            android:title="@string/salir"
            android:showAsAction="always|withText"/>

        </menu>
```

**MainActivity.java:**

```
public class MainActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity {

// Declare Variables
DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
ListView mDrawerList;
ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
MenuListAdapter mMenuAdapter;
String[] title;
Fragment fragment0 = new Fragment0();
//20 more

private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;
private CharSequence mTitle;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Get the view from drawer_main.xml
    setContentView(R.layout.drawer_main);

    // Get the Title
    mTitle = mDrawerTitle = "¿Qué buscás?";

    // Generate title
    title = new String[] { " ASD ", "CORTE LÁSER", "CORTE METALES",
            "CORTE POR CHORRO DE AGUA", "CURSOS", "EQUIPOS DE VIDEO", "FICHAS TÉCNICAS", 
            "FOTÓGRAFOS", "GRÁFICAS", "IMPRESIÓN 3D", "LIBRERÍAS Y PAPELERAS", "MAQUETAS Y PROTOTIPOS",
            "MODELADO 3D", "MODELOS", "PLÁSTICOS", "ROUTER", "SUBLIMACIÓN", "TELGOPOR", "TERMOFORMADO",
            "TORNERO MADERA", "TORNERO METALES", "VINILOS" };

    // Locate DrawerLayout in drawer_main.xml
    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

    // Locate ListView in drawer_main.xml
    mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview_drawer);

    // Set a custom shadow that overlays the main content when the drawer
    // opens
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow,
            GravityCompat.START);

    // Pass string arrays to MenuListAdapter
    mMenuAdapter = new MenuListAdapter(MainActivity.this, title);

    // Set the MenuListAdapter to the ListView
    mDrawerList.setAdapter(mMenuAdapter);

    // Capture listview menu item click
    mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());

    // Enable ActionBar app icon to behave as action to toggle nav drawer
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    // ActionBarDrawerToggle ties together the the proper interactions
    // between the sliding drawer and the action bar app icon
    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
            R.drawable.ic_drawer, R.string.drawer_open,
            R.string.drawer_close) {

        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onDrawerClosed(view);
        }

        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // Set the title on the action when drawer open
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
        }
    };

    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        selectItem(0);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {

        if (mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList)) {
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
        } else {
            mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(mDrawerList);
        }
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

// ListView click listener in the navigation drawer
private class DrawerItemClickListener implements
        ListView.OnItemClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {
        selectItem(position);
    }
}

private void selectItem(int position) {

    FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    // Locate Position
    switch (position) {
    case 0:
        ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment0);
        ft.addToBackStack(null);

        break;

    case 1:
        ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment1);
        ft.addToBackStack(null);
        break;

    // and 19 more cases
    }

    ft.commit();
    mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
    // Get the title followed by the position
    setTitle(title[position]);
    // Close drawer
    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);

}

public boolean onCreatedOptionMenu(Menu menu) {

    MenuInflater inflater = getSupportMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu1, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggles
    mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}

@Override
public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
    mTitle = title;
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
}
```

And the **Manifest.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
//...

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light.ForceOverflow" >
    <meta-data
     //...
</application>
```

Please if you need some more information to answer, ask me
(I have not yet allowed to post images to show you my app)

Sorry if I made a mistake when posting, also for my English, I notice that I am beginner coding.

---

**EDIT:**

I think that solves the fact that the menu does not appear on the actionbar with this code and deleting the menu.xml:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    SubMenu subMenu = menu.addSubMenu("Más");

    subMenu.add("Volver");
    subMenu.add("Contacto");
    subMenu.add("Salir");

    subMenu.getItem().setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);

    return true;
}
```

And added this in the onOptionsItemSelected already have in the MainActivity.java:

```
if (item.getTitle().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Publicá!")) {
        Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Publica.class);
        startActivity(in);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Publicá tu Negocio/Local/Emprendimiento", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


    } if (item.getTitle().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Contacto")) {
        Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Contacto.class);
        startActivity(in);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Contactate y reportanos ...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

     if (item.getTitle().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Salir")) {
         Intent i = new Intent(); i.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN); 
            i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME); i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP); 
            startActivity(i); android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
        Toast.makeText(this, "<-- Busca lo que necesitas", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

**Now  i Have something like** [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6sI8E.jpg)

---

**But** not know to generate the menu on the actionbar be an icon instead of text like "Type".

That is my problem now.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need to do with the item tags

```
 android:showAsAction=["ifRoom" | "never" | "withText" | "always" | "collapseActionView"]
```

always will always show you menus, never will let your menu item to come in the overflow mode..

set

```
android:showAsAction="never"
```

look [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/menu-resource.html) for more description.

Comment: thanks for the reply, I try and I read what you recommended, but it didn't work. I try something else, I edit the post and explained below.

Comment: here is your solution : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20444596/how-to-force-action-bar-overflow-icon-to-show/20445592#20445592