# ActionBar: setting button not appear in actionbar on samsung device

Tags: android, layout, android-actionbar

I implement layout for actionbar, including one button and other is setting button. I view in preview window (Intellij IDEA 13) I see as I expected but not on real device (samsung note 3).

Here is my layout:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- chat list. should appear as action button -->
    <item android:id="@+id/action_chat_list"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_chat_list"
          android:title="@string/action_chat"
          android:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
    <!-- Settings, should always be in the overflow -->
    <item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
          android:title="@string/action_settings"
          android:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

In Preview windows. I see as I expected:

[image: expected image]

But when I run on real device (Samsung Note 3).I cannot see Setting button:

[image: Real image]

I cannot understand why. Please tell me how to fix this.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Blackbelt has mentioned, because samsung has a menu button, so actionbar will automatically hide this. And I successfully follow [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20444596/how-to-force-action-bar-overflow-icon-to-show) to fix this problem. This really a small hack because you use java reflection api to change value of private attribute.

You put this code first when you start to run your application. You can subclass `Application` and put this code in `onCreate`

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    private static final String TAG = "MyApplication";

    private static Context mContext;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mContext = getApplicationContext();

        try {
            ViewConfiguration config = ViewConfiguration.get(this);
            Field menuKeyField = ViewConfiguration.class.getDeclaredField("sHasPermanentMenuKey");
            if(menuKeyField != null) {
                menuKeyField.setAccessible(true);
                menuKeyField.setBoolean(config, false);
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            // Ignore
        }
    }
}
```

And you declare this class in your android manifest file under `application` tag:

```
<application
            android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" android:allowBackup="true"
            android:name=".MyApplication">
</application>
```

Hope this help :)

Answer (score 3):

It because samsung has still a menu button. AFAIK there is no workaround for this

Comment: I've seen some workarounds but they're hacky. Best to just use the hardware menu key.

Comment: @blackbelt thanks for pointing me this point. I want same UI for all devices. I think i will implement this button by hands. Do you know how to get setting button ? (R.drawable.some_thing) thanks :)

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20444596/how-to-force-action-bar-overflow-icon-to-show

Answer (score 1):

Because you got the options button down to the left of your homebutton. When you thouch it the overflow menu will show on the screen. I guess it implemented in the background so it doenst show on devices that have a "real hardware" options button.

Heres a picture of the button i found on the web. http://cdn.webcazine.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/samsung_galaxy_s3_option_keys1.jpg?00d8d4