# Android layout issue. Missing three dots menu button

Tags: android, button, settings

I'm testing my app on various devices and I find out that on one phone (Kruger&Matz Muve) there is no three dots button on Action bar. I have some settings in there so it have to be there. I would nice if someone could help me with this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The overflow icon only appears on phones that have no menu hardware keys

[How to force action bar overflow icon to show](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20444596/how-to-force-action-bar-overflow-icon-to-show)

Comment: I had no idea... Thank you very much ;).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to show the three dots, irrespective of device menu button then you can call this method in your `Application` class `onCreate` method-

```
private void makeActionOverflowMenuShown() {
//devices with hardware menu button (e.g. Samsung Note) don't show action overflow menu
try {
    ViewConfiguration config = ViewConfiguration.get(this);
    Field menuKeyField = ViewConfiguration.class.getDeclaredField("sHasPermanentMenuKey");
    if (menuKeyField != null) {
        menuKeyField.setAccessible(true);
        menuKeyField.setBoolean(config, false);
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.d(TAG, e.getLocalizedMessage());
}
}
```

For more info [Android action bar not showing overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9739498/android-action-bar-not-showing-overflow)

Hope this will helps you.